# Improve C Build Time on Windows (gcc 3.4.5)

Tags: gcc, caching, compilation

I am programming on an older tech stack and I'd like to improve compile times. I've seen an application called [ccache](https://ccache.dev/) but it looks like it only runs on Unix systems. Is there any other way to improve compile times on windows besides running on more machines?

Answer (score 1):

- Use a build tool like `make` so you only need to rebuild modules that need re-generation.
- Compile with `-pipe` so that no temporary files are written (like preprocessed code, assembly) and pipes are used instead.  Whether or not this gives an advantage depends on how efficient the host can handle pipes and how fast the file system is.
- Use less debug info.  Dwarf-3 and higher results in big objects that have to be linked because every C macro is stored.  If you don't need to debug, compile with `-g0` resp. without debug info.
- Use less aggressive optimization.  The target  program might be less optimal, the host performance might increase. You can add options `-Q -v` which shows which flags are on and how much time is consumed for specific passes, which helps you figure out which passes are most time-consuming and which ones might be worth trading against target performance:

```
Execution times (seconds)
 phase setup             :   0.01 ( 5%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 3%) wall    1454 kB ( 5%) ggc
 phase parsing           :   0.19 (90%) usr   0.12 (100%) sys   0.31 (91%) wall   24281 kB (91%) ggc
 phase lang. deferred    :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 3%) wall     451 kB ( 2%) ggc
 phase opt and generate  :   0.01 ( 5%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.00 ( 0%) wall     372 kB ( 1%) ggc
 phase last asm          :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.01 ( 3%) wall     225 kB ( 1%) ggc
 |name lookup            :   0.06 (29%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.05 (15%) wall    1216 kB ( 5%) ggc
 |overload resolution    :   0.00 ( 0%) usr   0.00 ( 0%) sys   0.03 ( 9%) wall     693 kB ( 3%) ggc
 ...
```